# Pandas Inheritance Dropping Columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-inheritance

I created a base panda dataframe that is a variation on the existing panda's dataframe object.  When I call my function to `_set_auth_obj` it seems to set it on the object.  I can see the 'AUTH' column, but when I call a function from the base class `get_user()` an error is raised saying the column does not exist.

What is my issue here?  I know it's a problem with inheritance, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Thank you

Comment: please post a minimal code example to illustrate your issue. my first thought it that you're not returning your dataframe from the function - so any changes are stuck within the scope of `_set_auth_obj `

Comment: I figured it out, a function unrelated to this function was the issue.